# Generic model that can be used by several other models but only one at a time

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a Description model that can be used by several different models.
But the Description model can only have one at a time.

Lets say that i have these two models.

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    companyName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    VAT = models.CharField(max_length=35, unique=True)
```

I want both to have multiple descriptions. But the description object can only be linked to one model. A (dirty) solution that i found was this.

```
class Description(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2500, null=True, blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

In normal python you would just be able to have a list of description. But in django, this isn't possible. I've thought about using generic relations but that seems to work differently.
Why I want to do it like this?
Because I want to expand Description by using inheritance and I want to be able to use all those types of 'Descriptions' for multiple classes.

Comment: Do you mean you want `Account` and `CompanyProfile` to each have multiple descriptions?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, have been busy with school besides from this project.
And yes, they need to be able to have multiple descriptions.
And for example a 'Vacancy' model needs to be able to have multiple descriptions aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Django has got [Generic ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey)

But I feel a better way to implement this is to add OneToOne field in each model mapping to Description model

```
description= models.ForeignKey(Description, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: That would sort of work but I need to be able to have multiple descriptions.

Comment: Then go with Generic ForeignKey